# Vertical and horizontal reading with Laravel Excel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8, laravel-excel

I am currently using Laravel Excel (Maatwebsite) package for excel installation and reading. In my scenario, I first need to read horizontally to the database and then add the answers to the same question to the database by vertical reading.

So far, I have come to the Question field with the standard horizontal reading process, but in the **QuestionAnswer** column I need to read the answers of the question downwards.

How can I do that?
https://i.stack.imgur.com/yl1k9.png

Here is my save process but I don't know how to get Question Answer column.

```html
public function collection(Collection $rows)
    {
        foreach ($rows as $row) {
            $IDnumber = $row['IDnumber'];
            $name = $row['firstname'];
            $exam = $row['exam'];
            $course = $row['course'];
            $courseCode = $row['coursecode'];
            $question = $row['question'];

            $user = User::withTrashed()->firstOrCreate(
                ['IDnumber' => $IDnumber],
                [
                    'IDnumber' => $IDnumber,
                    'first_name' => $firstname, 
                ]
            );

            $q_insert = \Modules\Qulak\Entities\Question::create(
                [
                    'question' => $question,
                    'question_type' => 'MCQ',
                    'user_id' => $user->id,
                    'created_by' => Auth::user()->id,
                    'updated_by' => Auth::user()->id,
                ]
            );
        }
```

Thank You

Comment: Hello, show us the code you have so far and what errors do you get?

Comment: @Merijndk Sorry, thanks for reminding. I have now added my code snippet.